# ajax post call resulting in 422 error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to POST data on a form at a site (where I've registered) the following is my code:

```
$.ajax({
         url:'https://api.contentstack.io/v2/content_types/the_lazy_goose/entries/',
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json",
         data: JSON.stringify({
                title: "John", 
                url: "2pm", 
                multi_line: "Random Text using Post call"
            }),
        headers:{
                    access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                    api_key: 'xxxxxxxxx'
                },

        success: function() {
           alert("success");
        },
        error: function() {
               alert("ERROR");
            },
    });
```

This results in 422 (Unprocessable Entity), not sure where am going wrong.
*I've gone through http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity and understand that 'request_entity' & 'syntax of request' are fine

The site https://contentstackdocs.built.io/rest/api/content-management-api/ seem to be supporting Json data

Comment: Are you sure that `https://exampleurl.com/goose/entries/` is a valid URL allowing POST verb? Try this one instead: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Comment: Sorry, the link I mentioned is just a random text. The site I am Posting to allows POST, GET

Comment: Ok, are you sure then that your mentioned api allows `json` as contentType then? Maybe try not specifying or just for experimental purposes what does `application/xml` say, statuscode..?

Comment: @urbz Yes the site accepts json data(for sure). There are 2 status codes, the first one's 200 : OK and the second one's 422 : Unprocessable Entity

Comment: @urbz , I've updated the url of the site to which I am actually sending the data

Comment: Okay, the server interprets your request since it's not spitting out a `400 bad request` or `415 method not allowed`, so JSON is allowed and your req body is CORRECT but somewhere along the line maybe semantically erroneous.. are you following their model schema correctly?

Answer (score 0):

422 is used in rails when parameter validation fails. You may be missing some required parameters.

Also, I don't think `JSON.stringify` in data is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So I went through their contentstack.js file and used their Request method (instead of ajax) to POST data. The schema was wrong as well. So here's the code I used in the end:

```
function Request(options, callback) {
        HTTPRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
        var xhr = new HTTPRequest(),
            method = options.method || "POST",
            url = options.url,
            headers = options.headers;

        // make a request
        xhr.open(method, url, true);

        // set headers
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        for (var header in headers) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
        }

        // send stringify data
        if (options.body && method == "POST" || method == "PUT") {
            if (typeof options.body === 'object') {
                console.log("sending in data: options.body");
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.body));
            } else {
                xhr.send(options.body);
            }
        } else {
            xhr.send();
        }

        // collect response
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                var data = xhr.responseText;
                try {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Could not parse the response received from the server.');
                }

                if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                    callback(null, data);
                } else {
                    callback(data, null);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    var options =  {
            url: 'https://api.contentstack.io/v2/content_types/the_lazy_goose/entries/',
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                        access_token: 'xxxxxxx', //put auth token here
                        api_key: 'xxxxxxx'
                    },
            body: {
                      "entry": {
                        "title": "examplexx1",
                        "url": "/example10xxx1",
                        "multi_line": "multiline...!",
                        "_comment": "example comment"
                      }
                }
        };
```